# How to input text from a file and output to another

Tags: java, input, output

I am trying to take the string text from a text file input.txt, and line by line output that same text to an output file output.txt

I have tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    FileReader FR = new FileReader("C:\\FileLocation\\inputhashes.txt");
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(FR);
    PrintWriter PW = new PrintWriter("C:\\FileLocation\\outputtest.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
        PW.println(BR.readLine());
    } 
}
```

However this does 
not work and I am unsure why, the outputtest.txt file is completely empty.

When I try

```
 System.out.println(BR.readLine());
```

The console displays the correct results that I expect.

Comment: Try closing your files.

Comment: Also, you should watch your code formatting.  I've fixed it for you; see how much easier to read it is?

Comment: Ok thanks, ive tried that and still no luck

Comment: @kquinn, Please post what exactly you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code copy the content from one file to another, as mentioned by @Robert Harvey you may not be closing your files properly.

```
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ngueno\\Desktop\\File 1.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\ngueno\\Desktop\\File 2.txt"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

        String line;

        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            writer.write(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File inputFile = new File("inputFilePath");
File outputFile = new File("outputFilePath");

String output;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

try (BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {

    String line;
    while ( (line = buffRead.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
    }
    output = stringBuilder.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}

try (BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
    buffWrite.write(output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}
```